# Plotting data with pandas and matplotlib but no error also not showing data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
sickpay = pd.read_csv('sickleavedata.csv', index_col = 0)
      
  
plt.bar(sickpay, height=1)
plt.xlabel('JobTitle')
plt.ylabel('SickLeaveHours')
plt.title('Ages of different persons')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Trying to create a visual data but it wont show any data on the chart also not getting any errors

Comment: Check with debugging if your data is ok first

Comment: thank you, i didn't export the data right!

Answer (score 0):

as per the given code sickpay is your dataframe, not a column of a dataframe
so you can give a column as flows or use dataframe.plot(kind='bar') option

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
sickpay = pd.read_csv('sickleavedata.csv', index_col = 0)

sickpay.plot(kind='bar')

# or 
plt.bar(sickpay['column_name'], height=1)
```